# Converting a UTC date string into a localized date string in Ruby or Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a date, saved as a string:

```
my_utc_date_str = "2019-09-15T20:42:15"
```

This is saved as a UTC date string

My local zone, is:

```
America/Los_Angeles
```

What I would like to get is:

```
2019-09-15 13:42:15
```

Which is that UTC date, localized to USA Pacific Time Zone.

I tried various combinations of DateTime, Time and Date, with no luck. Any ideas bow to do this, without changing the Time Zone for the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Time.zone.parse("2019-09-15T20:42:15")
    .in_time_zone("America/Los_Angeles")
    .strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# => "2019-09-15 13:42:15"
```

See [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-strftime) for the ActiveSupport extension to Rubys time and date objects and [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-all) for a list of time zone mappings.

But for caching reasons you should consider localizing dates and times on the client side.